# Flash doesnt work, even in Google Chrome - SOLVED

Tags: release-juno, drivers, google-chrome, video-player

I use elementary OS 5.0 Juno with 5.2.16-050216-generic kernel but Flash Player doesn't work on all browsers (Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Chromium).

I did all of the following:

```
sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

But it doesn't' work still. What can I do else?

I use Lenovo Legion y530 laptop.

Comment: Does Flash work on your machine with the stock (currently, 4.15.0-65-generic for
Ubuntu 18.04) kernel?

Comment: @a-tokarev Thank you a lot! It works on stock kernel, I updated Flash by Google Chrome (chrome://components) and it works on all kernels now. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @dzierzak

> It had changed on my Elementary OS stock Kernel (4.15.X), I updated
>   Flash by Google Chrome (chrome://components) and it works on all
>   kernels now.